# I would like to know if my code is missing something, or if I wrote something incorrectly

Tags: java, window

I wrote code for the window of the specific game. And, for the some reason, my board cannot be shown on the window, unless I make the window resizable. And every time I run my programm, I have to resize my window a little bit for my board to be shown. Hope you understood and hope you can help me.

CODE:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window 
{
   public static final int WIDTH = 307, HEIGHT = 637;
   private JFrame window;
   private Board board;

public Window()
{
    window = new JFrame("TETRIS");
    window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);

    board = new Board();
    window.add(board);
    window.addKeyListener(board);   
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Window();
}
}
```

I was not sure if I need to write code of the board here, so I just wrote the first lines.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Board extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private BufferedImage blocks;
    private Shape[] shapes = new Shape[7];
    private Shape currentShape;
    private Timer timer;

    private final int blockSize = 30;
    private final int boardWidth = 10, boardHeight = 20;
    private int [][] board = new int [boardHeight][boardWidth];
    private final int FBS = 60;
    private final int delay = 1000/60;

    private boolean gameOver = false;

...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: changes on views should be done on the event thread using SwingUtilities.invokeLater so change your main to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has a thread responsible for view events so you should there change the view properties:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             new Window();
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.